# Stacked curves in geom_area plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to stack the graphs in the following example?

```
a<-as.POSIXlt("2013-07-01 00:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")
b<-as.POSIXlt("2013-07-08 00:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")
woche1<-sample(seq(as.numeric(a),by=60*60,length.out=200),200,T)
woche2<-sample(seq(as.numeric(b),by=60*60,length.out=200),200,T)
times<-c(woche1,woche2)
class(times)<-c("POSIXt","POSIXct") 
times<-as.POSIXlt(times,origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")
key<-sample(LETTERS[1:3],200,T)
df<-data.frame(times=times,order=factor(rep(1:2,each=100)), key=key)
p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=times))
p<-p + geom_area(aes(y = ..count.., fill = key, group = key),stat = "bin",position = 'stack')#,position = 'stack'
p<-p + facet_wrap( ~ order,scales="free_x")
p
```

Comment: You'll probably get more/faster/better help if you make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: ...specifically, I think you'll need to expand on exactly what you mean by "stack".

Comment: I have the same problem like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363881/ggplot2-geom-area-overlapping-instead-of-stacking is there a other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the question you linked in comment, problem is that in your data `times` are different for each `key` and so they can't be stacked.

To solve the problem you have to make time sequence that will be equal for all `key` values. For example made `tim.seq` that consist of 12 hour time segments

```
tim.seq<-seq(as.POSIXlt("2013-07-01 00:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT"),
             as.POSIXlt("2013-07-16 12:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT"),by="12 hours")
```

Now using function `cut()` add new column `times2` to existing data frame to show to which time segment each observation belongs.

```
df$times2<-cut(df$times,breaks=tim.seq)
```

Then using function `ddply()` from library `plyr` aggregate your data to have number of occurrence of each time step. Add times2 should be made as POSIXct class for plotting.

```
df2<-ddply(df,.(order,times2,key),nrow)
df2$times2<-as.POSIXct(df2$times2)
```

To this data frame you should add also missing time periods to get pretty look (0 values). This can be done by making all possible combination of `order`, `times2` and `key` and then merging with data frame `df2`. This will make NA values in `V1` for missing times, they are replaced with 0.

```
df3<-expand.grid(unique(df2$order),unique(df2$times2),unique(df2$key))
colnames(df3)<-c("order","times2","key")
df4<-merge(df2,df3,by=c("times2","order","key"),all=TRUE)
df4$V1[is.na(df4$V1)]<-0
```

Now you can get stacked area plot.

```
ggplot(df4,aes(x=times2,y=V1,fill=key))+geom_area(stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap( ~ order,scales="free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: _As already mentioned in the question you linked in comment, problem is that in your data times are different for each key and so they can't be stacked._ Yes I know, but I am looking for a solution to make the time interval more flexible, how can I do this e.g. for all 3h?

Comment: thx, is there a function to sort the data.frame df2 by time in one command? I see you reorder df2 because it would print df2 not well.

Comment: @Klaus I'm not sure that I understand you. df2 is allready sorted by order variable and then time2 variable. If you change the ddply(df,.(order,times2,key),nrow) to ddply(df,.(times2,order,key),nrow) then it will be sorted by times2 and then by order

Comment: sry now I see whhat you do in df3 and df4 there are some time entries left in df2.

Comment: I realy enjoy the solution and learn to apply basic function cut and merge, I think that will help me in future alot.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a bit unclear, but I think you want the graphs to be on top of each other instead of next to each other. To do this just add `nrow = 2` to the facet_wrap

p<-p + facet_wrap( ~ order,scales="free_x", nrow = 2)

If this is not what you mean, please tell is what exactly you want.